# how to prove $ax + by = cx + dy \implies a = c, b = d$?

Tags: arithmetic, self-learning

Actually the question is in the title. I just have saw such a method

$$
ax + by = cx + dy \implies  a = c, b = d
$$

in my textbook, so I can assume it is true, but I'm very interested on proving this, and failed to do this myself. Could anyone explain this, please.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the equality supposed to be true for all $x$ and $y$?

Comment: What are $a, b, c, d, x,$ and $y$? If $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent vectors, and $a, b, c, d$ are scalars, then this is true. If all six are numbers, then it is not necessarily true that $a = c$ and $b = d$.

Comment: I think they are both supposed to be 1, cause I saw this in the proving of coordinate transformation formula. x and y are the orts of the x and y axes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this equality holds for all $x$ and $y$ then

- $x=1$ and $y=0$ gives $a=c$
- $x=0$ and $y=1$ gives $b=d$.

Comment: and what if both x and y are 1?

Comment: We proved that $ax+by=ax+by$ which is always true.

Answer (score 1):

$ax + by = cx + dy \implies (a-c)x+(b-d)y=0$

if we assume that neither $x$ nor $y$ is zero and they don't have any know relation with each other (for example if $x=-y$ then $a-c=b-d$) then we can conclude that $a=c$ and $b=d$

Comment: how you can be sure that if $x \neq 0, y \neq 0 \implies a - c = b - d$ ? Could you please detail this?

Comment: because I assumed that if $x=-y$ then you can omit $x$ (because it is not zero ) and you'll have $(a-c)-(b-d)=0$ and so $a-c=b-d$

Answer (score 1):

The equality does not need to hold for all real x and y, i.e. the domain of the values of x and y might be a subset of the real numbers, or imaginary numbers or whole numbers etc. The important thing is that the values should be independent. If x and y can take on values independently then we can have two cases:

First choose any arbitrary value of x and y and find the relations between a,b,c and d. Then keeping the value of x the same vary the value of y for the second equations relating a,b,c and d. This will give the result b=d.

Similarly do the same keeping the value of y the same and varying the value of x and it will lead to the result a=c.